# Flutter: ¿Como validar cuando mi app se cierre inesperadamente?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

Tengo una app en PlayStore, donde algunos usuarios reportan que se cierra de forma repentina, he hecho testeos con 3 telefonos y varios emuladores y no encuentro ninguna parte del debug que haga que se cierra la app. Funciona bien hasta donde la he probado.

Alguna sugerencia para testearla? He hecho mi mayor esfuerzo en buscar bugs que lo provoquen, pero no los he encontrado.

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  //init db sqlite
  await DatabaseHandler().initializeDB();

  //keep user loged in
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var email = preferences.getString('email');

  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: email == null ? percentIndicator() : percentIndicator(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Screen main
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Iniciar Sesión',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: UltimosCursosLista(), // home: loginScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Podrías añadir en que dispositivos sucede eso, marca/modelo/OS version, también podrías usar Sentry para poder ver los errores en la nube.

Comment: Como menciona Diego, creo que lo mejor es añadir algún gestor para controlar los errores en la app. Sentry, si no recuerdo mal es de pago o al menos, no era 100 % gratuito. Podrías probar con crashlytics de firebase. también. La idea de estos gestores es que cuando hay un fallo en la app que no es capturado y por consiguiente, hace que la app "crashee", envían el error e información del dispositivo, como el modelo, al servidor, para que puedas revisarlo y obtener más detalles.

Comment: En tu Google Play Console puedes ver exactamente  en qué modelos, qué versión de Android y más. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859174?hl=en